# Keras ImageDataGenerator rescale values to [-0.5, 0.5]

Tags: image-processing, keras

`ImageDataGenerator` class from Keras has parameter `rescale` which changes pixel value from [0, 255] to [0, 1]. Is it possible to change it to [-0.5, 0.5]?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You may be able to rescale to `[0, 0.5]` but not to `-0.5`

Answer (score 1):

As it is specified in the [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> rescale: rescaling factor. Defaults to None. If None or 0, no
>   rescaling is applied, otherwise we multiply the data by the value
>   provided (after applying all other transformations).

So it is not possible to achieve [-0.5, 0.5] with this parameter, but you could achieve [0, 1] range with 1/255. factor.

For rescaling the images to [-0.5, 0.5] range you could do interp each image after data agumentation:

```
np.interp(image, (0, 255), (-0.5, 0.5))
```